# Insert class values into SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, database, insert

I am working on a C# project that is going to be used to read in values from an excel spreadsheet, clean the values to make sure the data is correct, then insert said values into a database table. That being said I am also fairly new to C# (this is my first "big" project"), so with the help of a coworker we have two out of the three requirements coded.

With that background out of the way, I am having trouble calling the class that has the values stored so I can insert them into the required table. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ReadExcel
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() { DisplayAlerts = false, Visible = false };

    public List<Attorney> listOfAttys = Helpers.getAttorneys();
    public List<LegalTransactionRec> listofTransactions = Helpers.insertRecords();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setAttyList();
    }


    private void setAttyList()
    {
        foreach (var item in listOfAttys.Select(x => x.Caption))
            cmbAtty.Items.Add(item);


    }


    public void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtbxFilename.Text); 

        try
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            List<LegalTransactionRec> lstTran = new List<LegalTransactionRec>();


                for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                  {
                       lstTran.Add(new LegalTransactionRec()
                        {

                            AccountNumber = CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString()),
                            CostAmount = TryToParse(CleanAmount(xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString())),
                            SSN = CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 6].Value2.ToString()),
                            TransactionDate = CheckDate(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToDate()),
                            Description = xlRange.Cells[i, 8].Value2.ToString(),
                            TransactionCode = CheckNull(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToInt())
                        });
                  }
                }

            if (validateHeader(worksheet))
            {




            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }


        excelApp.Quit();
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtbxFilename.Text = null;

        System.IO.Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    txtbxFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    myStream.Close();
                    myStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }


    private bool validateHeader(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Worksheet)
    {
        if (Worksheet == null)
            return false;

        bool isValid = false;

        //get header row
        //check all cell values

        return isValid;
    }

    public int CheckNull(int intVal)
    {
        int cleanValue;
        if (intVal == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanValue = intVal;
        }

        return cleanValue;
    }

    public string CleanString(String strVal)
    {
        string cleanValue;
        if (strVal == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanValue = Regex.Replace(strVal," ", "").Replace("$","").Replace("-","");
        }

        return cleanValue;
    }

    public string CleanAmount(String amt)
    {
        string cleanAmt;
        if (amt == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            cleanAmt = Regex.Replace(amt, "(", "-").Replace(")", "").Replace("$","").Replace("[^0-9]+", "").Replace(" ","");
        }
        return cleanAmt;
    }

    public static void TryToParse(string strAmt)
    {
        decimal decAmt;

        bool result = Decimal.TryParse(strAmt, out decAmt);

    }

    public DateTime CheckDate(DateTime tranDate)
    {
        DateTime date;

        if (tranDate == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
        }
        else
        {
            date = tranDate;
        }

        return date;
    }

}

public class Attorney
{
    public string AttorneyID { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public string AttorneyName { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class LegalTransactionRec
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string CostAmount { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public int BatchID { get; set; }
    public Attorney Attorney { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TransactionCode { get; set; }
}


public class ReviewOutput
{
}

public class ApprovedOutput
{ 
}

}
```

Here is the other part:

EDIT: I added some code to before the insert statement begins, I figured I might be able to use DataRows like my coworker used when he created the `select statement`. My problem now is just figuring out how to point to my class that is holding the values I need to insert.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadExcel
{
  class Helpers
  {

    public static List<Attorney> getAttorneys()
    {
        List<Attorney> lst = new List<Attorney>();

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendLine("SELECT ");
        sql.AppendLine("  V.ATTORNEY_ID, V.ORGANIZATION_ID, A.NAME, ( '(' || V.ATTORNEY_ID || ') - ' || a.name ) as caption");
        sql.AppendLine("FROM ");
        sql.AppendLine("  VENDOR_PORTAL.organization_attys V, ATLAS.RLGLENTY A ");
        sql.AppendLine("WHERE ");
        sql.AppendLine("  V.ATTORNEY_ID = A.ID_CODE (+) ");
        sql.AppendLine("  and V.organization_id != 122 ");
        sql.AppendLine("  and V.organization_id is not null ");
        sql.AppendLine("ORDER BY A.NAME ASC ");
        using (DataTable dt = DataManager.GetData(sql))
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    lst.Add(new Attorney()
                    {
                        AttorneyName = dr["name"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["name"].ToString(),
                        OrganizationID = int.Parse(dr["organization_id"].ToString()),
                        AttorneyID = dr["attorney_id"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["attorney_id"].ToString(),
                        Caption = dr["caption"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "" : dr["caption"].ToString()
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }

        return lst;
    }

    public static List<LegalTransactionRec> insertRecords()
    {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        using (DataTable dt = DataManager.GetData(sql))
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    sql.AppendLine("INSERT INTO PCOSCETTE.LEGAL_TRANSCATIONS (BATCH_ID, ACCOUNT, ATTORNEY_ID, ORG_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE, DATE_INSERTED, TRANSACTION_CODE, AMOUNT, DESCRIPTION, DEBTOR_SSN");
                    sql.AppendLine("VALUES ( (select max(batch_id) from pcoscette.legal_transaction_batch_info),");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Any point in the right direction would be a life saver, thanks. Also if I have forgotten anything in my original post please let me know and I will add it.

Comment: I believe that it would be better to use IDbCommand interface (SqlCommand for MS SQL server) with parameters to make inserts to the database. Please take a look at some ORM frameworks like NHibernate or BLToolkit to organize data layer access (map class properties to the database parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of your `Class` and assign the desired `values` or variables to by using `class properties`
Here is an small  example with your code.

Your Class-

```
public class LegalTransactionRec
{
 public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
 public string CostAmount { get; set; }
 public string SSN { get; set; }
 public int BatchID { get; set; }
 public Attorney Attorney { get; set; }
 public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public int TransactionCode { get; set; }
}
```

Create Instance of your class;

```
LegalTransactionRec objLegal= new LegalTransactionRec(); //objLegal is instance name you can name it as you want
```

Assign values to your class properties.

```
objLegal.AccountNumber= someValue1 // or variable
objLegal.CostAmount= someValue2 // or variable
........
```

Comment: I already assigned values to the class properties, you can find that code inside the `for loops`. I also assume that if I create a new instance of the class, then these values will no longer be available.

Comment: So where is the problem? Can you be more specific about your problem

Comment: Sorry thought I was clear in the original post, I am having a problem taking these values and calling them in the `insert statement` part of my code. The insert code can be found in the second portion of code I supplied. I figured I'd need a `foreach loop`, but when I try to point to the `rowcount`, it cant be found.